# Animate.css classes only when current slider is active

Tags: javascript, css, slider, animate.css, unslider

I'm using the [unslider](http://unslider.com) plugin.

All i want is to trigger the animate.css class on the elements inside the slider **only** when the current slider is on.

If i'm not mistaken, unslider adds a class .active in the current active slider, so what i tried to do is to put a "test" class inside the elements i wanted to animate and then add this css:

```
.active .test{
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn  !important;
    animation-name: bounceIn  !important;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .75s !important;
    animation-duration: .75s  !important;
  }
```

It does not work, though.

You can see it online here: http://www.felipegrin.com/test-two/

Comment: Try and write a more specific path to your .active classes.

e.g. > .unslider-carousel .active .test

Comment: solved! I used the bootstrap carousel rather than unslider.